# Similar Objects Quantity

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have an assignment to make this Restaurant Program. it Consists of an Order Class a product class and the main class. Order has an ArrayList to hold the products. I create an instance of the Order and then I add items through my main method.A product has a name(string) a bar-code(string), and a price(float).

Then I have to output a receipt.But what if a customer orders more of one product? Do I instantiate everything one by one? Is a second Beer Product independent? Should I hold quantities somehow? If I want to add a second beer I have to create a new product Beer2 etc? I don't know beforehand how many products each order will hold and the quantity of each so Is this way of instantiating proper? Thanks

Note: it is still incomplete as I want to deal with this before I move on.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MyRestaurantTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    Paraggelia order1 = new Paraggelia(currentDate,"11B");
    Product Beer = new Product("Amstel","111222",1.20f);
    Product Beef = new Product("Pork Beef","333444",8.50f);

    order1.add(Beer);
    order1.add(Beef);
    System.out.println(order1.getReceipt(30f));

}

}
```

Order Class(nevermind the name Paraggelia I gave it)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

/*Notes to self:
 * -Work on Comments
 * -Javadocs maybe? 
 * -try to optimize the rough code.
 */

/*Order class*/
public class Paraggelia {

    private Date orderDate;
    private String tableNumber;
    private int customerCount;
    private ArrayList<Product> listOfItems;

    /*Constructor(s)*/

    Paraggelia(Date orderDate,String tableNumber){
        this.orderDate=orderDate;
        this.tableNumber=tableNumber;
        this.listOfItems = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }


    /*Add && Delete Products from the Order class*/

    public void add(Product p){
        if(p == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }else{
        listOfItems.add(p);
        }
    }

    public void delete(Product p){
        if(p == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        else
        {
            listOfItems.remove(p);
        }
    }

    /** Calculates and returns the total price
     * Usually called directly as a parameter of getReceipt function
     * */
    public static float getTotalPrice(){

        return 0;
    }

    /** Creates and returns the final Receipt! 
     * -Display must consist of:
     * Item$ - BarCode# - Item Amount#
     * Total Price#
     * Table Number#
     */
    public  String getReceipt(float totalPrice){
        StringBuilder receipt = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i =0; i<this.listOfItems.size();i++){
        receipt.append(listOfItems.get(i).getName());
        receipt.append("\n");
        }

        return new String(receipt);
    }


    /*Getters && Setters */
    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }
    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }
    public String getTableNumber() {
        return tableNumber;
    }
    public void setTableNumber(String tableNumber) {
        this.tableNumber = tableNumber;
    }
    public int getCustomerCount() {
        return customerCount;
    }
    public void setCustomerCount(int customerCount) {
        this.customerCount = customerCount;
    }

}
```

Product Class:

```
public class Product {

    private String Name;
    private String barCode;
    private float sellingPrice;

    /*Constructors: */
    Product(){}

    Product(String Name,String barCode,float sellingPrice){
        this.Name=Name;
        this.barCode=barCode;
        this.sellingPrice=sellingPrice;             
    }

    /*Getters & Setters*/
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }

    public void setBarCode(String barCode) {
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }

    public float getSellingPrice() {
        return sellingPrice;
    }

    public void setSellingPrice(float sellingPrice) {
        this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ArrayList ( List ) you can use Map ( HashMap for example )

**MyRestaurantTester**

```
public class MyRestaurantTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        Paraggelia order1 = new Paraggelia(currentDate,"11B");
        Product Beer = new Product("Amstel","111222",1.20f);
        Product Beef = new Product("Pork Beef","333444",8.50f);

        order1.add(Beer, 1);
        order1.add(Beef, 5);
        System.out.println(order1.getReceipt(30f));

    }

}
```

**Paraggelia**

```
class Paraggelia {

    private Date orderDate;
    private String tableNumber;
    private int customerCount;
    private Map<Product, Integer> listOfItems;

    /*Constructor(s)*/

    Paraggelia(Date orderDate,String tableNumber){
        this.orderDate=orderDate;
        this.tableNumber=tableNumber;
        this.listOfItems = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();
    }


    /*Add && Delete Products from the Order class*/

    public void add(Product p, int quantity){
        if(p == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }else{
            listOfItems.put(p, quantity);
        }
    }

    public void delete(Product p){
        if(p == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        else
        {
            listOfItems.remove(p);
        }
    }

    /** Calculates and returns the total price
     * Usually called directly as a parameter of getReceipt function
     * */
    public static float getTotalPrice(){

        return 0;
    }

    /** Creates and returns the final Receipt!
     * -Display must consist of:
     * Item$ - BarCode# - Item Amount#
     * Total Price#
     * Table Number#
     */
    public  String getReceipt(float totalPrice){
        StringBuilder receipt = new StringBuilder();

        for(Map.Entry<Product,Integer> entry : this.listOfItems.entrySet()) {
            Product product = entry.getKey();
            Integer quantity = entry.getValue();

            receipt.append(product.getName() + " " + quantity);
            receipt.append("\n");
        }

        return new String(receipt);
    }


    /*Getters && Setters */
    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }
    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }
    public String getTableNumber() {
        return tableNumber;
    }
    public void setTableNumber(String tableNumber) {
        this.tableNumber = tableNumber;
    }
    public int getCustomerCount() {
        return customerCount;
    }
    public void setCustomerCount(int customerCount) {
        this.customerCount = customerCount;
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

Pork Beef 5

Amstel 1

Answer (score 0):

Three basic approaches come to mind:

- Instantiate each product individually
- Instead of `ArrayList`, have another structure that can associate items with quantities; or,
- Make a class `Article`, which belongs to a `Product`: `Product beerProduct = new Product("beer", "0129", 1.37); Article beer = new Article(beerProduct), beer2 = new Article(beerProduct)`.

The first solution gives you a lot of flexibility (e.g. to discount individual articles for, say, being damaged). The second solution is more economical with objects. The third one captures the intuition that all the Heineken bottles are the same. It is really up to what you want to do - both approaches are equally valid, for some purpose.